# Get data from webpage in Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium

I've made a small piece of code in titanium to get data from a webpage. But when i run the application and press the button that will trigger the function it doesn't show the data.

Can someone explain to me what i am doeing wrong, and why i did it wrong?

This is my code:

```
// include needed files
Ti.include('responsive.js');
//Ti.include('http_connection.js');


//Create the screen

//The home screen
var homeWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  exitOnClose: true,
  fullscreen: false,
  title: 'Advanced'
});

var homeView = Ti.UI.createView({
  backgroundColor: 'white'
});

var homeLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    top: 20,
    left: 30,
    height: 30,
    text: 'Test text',
    color: 'black',
    font: {fontSize: 18}
});

var testButton1 = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: 'test',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    top: 55,
    left: per10,
    width:per60,
    height: 30,
    color: 'black',
    font: {fontSize: 14} 
});

var testButton2 = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: 'test2',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    top: 95,
    left: per10,
    width:per60,
    height: 30,
    color: 'black',
    font: {fontSize: 14} 
});

testButton2.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    Ti.API.info("Button Clicked");
    http_con();
    Ti.API.info("Button Clicked 2");
    //alert('test');
});

function http_con() {
    Ti.API.info('hya');

    //Database connection
    var http_client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
    http_client.open('POST', 'http://rdbomers-hp:89/ceres');

    //If variables has been send
    http_client.onload = function() {
        Ti.API.info('subjects: ' + this.responseText);
        callback(this.responseText);
    };

    //If there is an error
    http_client.onerror = function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('error: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
    };
};

//Creating the application
//Home screen
homeWindow.add(homeView);
homeView.add(homeLabel);
homeView.add(testButton1);
homeView.add(testButton2);
homeWindow.open();
```

I have put thi `Ti.API.info('hya')` in the function to check if it gets there, it shows the HYA, but i want it to show the content of the webpage.

Comment: First, you should sure that page is online. http://rdbomers-hp:89/ceres -> 0 NO RESPONSE with POST or GET (Chrome Extension - Advanced Rest Client)

Comment: The page is online, it is an local host server

Comment: set the request type to get, and see if it works, also try to open the  url in your browser also, if it opens cool otherwise you may have to see if its accessible from device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define callbacks before calling `.open` - like this

```
function http_con() {
    Ti.API.info('hya');

    //Database connection
    var http_client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();

    //If variables has been send
    http_client.onload = function() {
        Ti.API.info('subjects: ' + this.responseText);
        callback(this.responseText);
    };

    //If there is an error
    http_client.onerror = function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('error: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
    };

    http_client.open('POST', 'http://rdbomers-hp:89/ceres');

};
```